# How can I update a 3D plot in SymPy while it's shown?

Tags: python, plot, sympy

I'd like to plot a certain 3D-function where a parameter changes over time using the sympy.plotting module.

I don't want several plots in one figure, I want one plot that updates, e.g. a parabola getting wider or narrower. How can I do that? I didn't find anything in the docs, but maybe I just missed it...

Comment: have u looked here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-update-a-plot-in-matplotlib/

Comment: @LiorCohen Yes, can I use that with sympy functions? Does matplotlib have 3d plotting capabilities?

Comment: Correct. According to SymPy documentation it's using the `matplotlib` backend for rendering of the plots, hence you can use all modifications that matplotlib makes available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the link provided by @Lior Cohen. You just need to convert your symbolic expression to a numerical function. Here is how I would do it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp

# symbolic expression
x, y, t = sp.symbols("x, y, t")
expr = sp.cos((x**2 + y**2) * t)
# convert to numerical function
func = sp.lambdify([x, y, t], expr)

# numerical discretization 
x, y = np.mgrid[-2:2:20j, -2:2:20j]
# evaluate the function at time t=0
z = func(x, y, 0)
  
plt.ion()
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection="3d")
surface = ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, color="b")
ax.set_zlim(-1, 1)

for t in np.linspace(0, 1):
    # sadly, its not possible to update a surface.
    # hence, we remove the previous and add a new one
    surface.remove()
    # add a new 3d surface
    surface = ax.plot_surface(x, y, func(x, y, t), color="b")
    fig.canvas.draw()
    fig.canvas.flush_events()
```